# Can't create Dask dataframe although Pandas dataframe gets created for the same query (sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchTableError)

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy, dask, cx-oracle

Hello I am trying to create a Dask Dataframe by pulling data from an Oracle Database as:

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
import dask 
import dask.dataframe as dd 

# Build connection string/URL
user='user'
pw='pw'
host = 'xxx-yyy-x000'
port = '9999'
sid= 'XXXXX000'

ora_uri = 'oracle+cx_oracle://{user}:{password}@{sid}'.format(user=user, password=pw, sid=cx_Oracle.makedsn(host,port,sid))
tstquery ="select ID from EXAMPLE where rownum <= 5"


# Create Pandas Dataframe from ORACLE Query pull 
tstdf1 = pd.read_sql(tstquery
                    ,con = ora_uri
                    )
print("Dataframe tstdf1 created by pd.read_sql")
print(tstdf1.info())


# Create Dask Dataframe from ORACLE Query pull 
tstdf2 = dd.read_sql_table(table = tstquery
                          ,uri = ora_uri 
                          ,index_col = 'ID'
                         )
print(tstdf2.info())
```

As you can see the Pandas DF gets created but not the Dask DF. Following is the stdout:

```
Dataframe tstdf1 created by pd.read_sql
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 1 columns):
ID    5 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1)
memory usage: 120.0 bytes
None


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dk_test.py", line 40, in <module>
    ,index_col = 'ID'
  File "---------------------------python3.6/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/sql.py", line 103, in read_sql_table
    table = sa.Table(table, m, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine, schema=schema)
  File "<string>", line 2, in __new__
  File "---------------------------python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 130, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "---------------------------python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 496, in __new__
    metadata._remove_table(name, schema)
  File "---------------------------python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "---------------------------python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 154, in reraise
    raise value
  File "---------------------------python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 491, in __new__
    table._init(name, metadata, *args, **kw)
  File "---------------------------python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 585, in _init
    resolve_fks=resolve_fks,
  File "---------------------------python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 609, in _autoload
    _extend_on=_extend_on,
  File "---------------------------python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2147, in run_callable
    return conn.run_callable(callable_, *args, **kwargs)
  File "---------------------------python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1604, in run_callable
    return callable_(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "---------------------------python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 429, in reflecttable
    table, include_columns, exclude_columns, resolve_fks, **opts
  File "---------------------------python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/reflection.py", line 653, in reflecttable
    raise exc.NoSuchTableError(table.name)
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchTableError: select ID from EXAMPLE where rownum <= 5
```

Needless to say, the table exists (As demonstrated by the creation of the Pandas DF), the Index is on 
the col ID as well. What is the problem ?